# JavaScript run time error while deploy on IIS Server

Tags: javascript

I am using Telerik Kendo UI controls and Telerik Reports, I have Telerik HTML5 Report Viewer. Java Script run time error on report viewer.

The issue is that I am using Telerik Reports not working when I deploy project IIS Server, else I run the project on IIS Express then Reports shown correctly.

```
$('#reportViewer1').show();
                //update the viewer's reportSource
                var reportViewer = $("#reportViewer1").data("telerik_ReportViewer");
                reportViewer.reportSource({
                    report: $('#reportName').val(),
```

reportViewer.reportSource shows run time error.

Comment: Well what does the error say?

Comment: Any body who deployed telerik reports in ASP.NET MVC using Telerik HTML 5 Report Viewer

Comment: That's a strange error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution to above problem, i added reference Reprot Viewer Js and Css files to my Layout page instead of Bundling references.